# Reassign point ID in Points tab?

Tags: leica-geo-office

I have measures many dozens of lines and every now and then there is a point wrongly numbered. By sorting on Orthographic Height in the `points` tab I can easily find these, for example:

```
4009 : -0.2039 (1 measurement)
3009 : -0.2033 (Many measurements)
```

Obviously 4009 should be assigned to 3009. In the `level-proc`tab you can reassign a measured tippled by right clicking the point you want to reassign. Right now I have to search within all my measured lines for point `4009` to reassign it in `level-proc`. I should be able to do this in points or at the very least find out what line it was measured in  automated way.

Same goes for doubles that deviate to much. If the average limit is exceeded Geo-Office automatically discards it that specific point. But in most cases that specific point is incorrectly numbered and need to be assigned to another point ID.

So my question in a nutshell:

- How can I assign a point to another ID from the `Points`tab?
- Or how can I quickly find the line where this point was measured to modify it in the line in `Level-Proc`?

My current method is rather devious. I am writing down each point that needs to be changed, it are many dozens ID's so I cannot remember them all. Then I'm looking through all my lines in `level-Proc` to find either the incorrect ID or a ID with a incorrect height (also an incorrect ID essentially). In level proc I can assign ID's to other ID's so I fix it here. I'm really hoping to do this in `Points`, changing ID's is possible but only if they do not exist and 99 out of 100 times I need to assign it to a existent ID.